# redirect page in phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, html, cordova

PhoneGap is not able to open the internal link.In my html I am using href tag But unable to load the webpage..Can anyone please suggest how to redirect one html page to another html page in phonegap ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Code ::

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:goToNext()">Next Page</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function goToNext() {
       window.location.href = './NextPage.html';
    }

</script>
```

Hopefully, This will help you for navigating to a new page.

Thanks.

Comment: Good. Pleasure to help you. Enjoy Coding.

Comment: @Tanya Prashar- please mark this answer so that others come to know that its the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

How About redirecting page automatically in iphone?
For example, i have used `$.mobile.changePage("login.html");` based on jQuery Mobile, but the app just displays a blank page.

Whether to use `$.mobile.changePage();` to redirect page in iphone?

It runs well in Android.